# Convergence of sequence of compositions of operators on a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

This was quite involved, I'd like to make sure I'm not making any mistakes here. Thanks in advance for criticisms, suggestions and other comments.

$\textbf{Proposition}$: Let $X$ be a Banach space and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $S_n,T_n \in B(X)$. Suppose for each $x \in X$, both $(S_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}},(T_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge. Then there exists $P \in B(X)$ such that for each $x \in X$, we have $P(x)=\lim(S_n \circ T_n)(x)$.

$\textbf{Proof}$: Define the function $P: X \to X$ by $$P(x) = \lim S_n(\lim T_n(x)).$$ Then by the Uniform Boundedness Theorem, $P \in B(X)$. Now, let $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $x \in X$. We know there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$n\in\mathbb{N}_{>N_1}\Rightarrow\|\lim S_n(\lim T_n(x)) - S_n(\lim T_n(x))\|<\epsilon/4;$$ furthermore we know there exists $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$(1) \ \ n\in\mathbb{N}_{>N_2}\Rightarrow\|\lim(S_n \circ T_n)(x)-(S_n \circ T_n)(x)\|<\epsilon/4;$$ we also know that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $N_3\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$(2) \ \  m\in\mathbb{N}_{>N_3}\Rightarrow\|S_n(\lim T_n(x))-(S_n \circ T_m)(x)\|<\epsilon/4,$$ since $S_n$ is continuous, so it commutes with $\lim$; finally, we know that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>N_2}$, there exists $N_4\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$(3) \ \ m\in\mathbb{N}_{>N_4}\Rightarrow\|(S_n \circ T_m)(x) - \lim(S_n \circ T_n)(x)\|\leq$$ $$\|(S_n \circ T_n)(x)-\lim(S_n \circ T_n)(x)\|<\epsilon/4,$$ where the second inequality holds by $(1)$. Let then $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>N_1,N_2}$; we know there exists $N_3\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $(2)$ and $N_4\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $(3)$, and for $m\in\mathbb{N}_{>N_3,N_4}$, we have that $$\|P(x)-(S_n \circ T_n)(x)\|=\|\lim S_n(\lim T_n(x)) - (S_n \circ T_n)(x)\|\leq$$ $$\|\lim S_n(\lim T_n(x)) - S_n(\lim T_n(x))\|+\|S_n(\lim T_n(x))-(S_n \circ T_m)(x)\|+$$ $$\|(S_n \circ T_m)(x) - \lim(S_n \circ T_n)(x)\|+\|\lim(S_n \circ T_n)(x)-(S_n \circ T_n)(x)\|<$$ $$\epsilon/4+\epsilon/4+\epsilon/4+\epsilon/4 = \epsilon.$$

Comment: It's a bit difficult to read with all the dummy variables being $n$.  How do you get $N_3$?

Comment: @Aweygan This is the best idea I could come up with so far. $N_3$ from prior to the edit is now $N_4$. I realize it is still sort of unclear why there is such $N_4$. I'll think more about it later, but appreciate any other help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current state of your proof is confusing, particularly when you start using $N_3$ and $N_4$, and longer than necessary. Here's a proof that doesn't use so many $N$s.

By the uniform boundedness principle, the sequences $\{S_n\}$ and $\{T_n\}$ converge pointwise to operators $S$ and $T$ in $B(X)$, respectively.  Put $P=ST$.  Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in X$ be given, and put $M=\sup_n\|S_n\|$. Then there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for $n\geq N$ we have $\|S_nTx-STx\|<\varepsilon/2$ and $\|T_nx -Tx\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$. Hence for $n\geq N$ we have

$$\|S_nT_nx-Px\|\leq\|S_n\|\|T_nx-Tx\|+\|S_nTx-Px\|<M\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon.$$

Thus $\lim_nS_nT_nx=Px$, and since $x\in X$ was arbitrary we know $\{S_nT_n\}$ converges strongly to $P$.